# Rails run all tests except one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I want to run all my unit tests on my ruby on rails project except one. This is because i have pdf generation tests that don't work when ran by travic CI. So on travis I want to run all tests except the pdf generation tests. Is there any check i can do? Is there a way to check if the application is running locally or on travis CI? Both are test environments.
Here is my travis.yml

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- '2.1.5'
script:
- 'bundle exec rake'
- 'bundle exec rubocop'
- 'bundle exec rails_best_practices'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your `travis.yml`

```
env:
  - SKIP_PDF_TESTS=true
```

and the modify your test to

either test or skip something

```
def the_pdf_test
  if ENV['SKIP_PDF_TEST']
    skip("the pdf test")
  else
    ... the actual test
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `skip` a test in minitest using [MiniTest::Assertions#skip](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-skip)

From inside your test, just call the skip() method, like this:

```
skip("Its generating PDF")
```